# Is there a way that I can get HERE's API traffic static map (or ground truth)

Tags: python, here-api, network-traffic

I am getting real-time traffic data from [HERE Traffic Flow](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/topics/concepts/flow.html) API, and in every request I get a different map, as in, if there is no traffic data in a specific segment of the road, the segment is not returned. is there a source where I can get the full map so I can treat it as my ground truth? please guide me to an API documentation if possible
Thank you!